# Prevent keyboard tab behind Loading control

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I am using the Windows Community ToolKit `Loading` control. I set the `Background="Transparent"` to prevent pointer tap to UI elements behind the loading control, but still I can use keyboard tab to set focus to UI controls behind the control. Is there an easy/elegant way to prevent keyboard tab into such behind controls.

- I could use `IsEnabled` on the panel/container control, but I don't like the style of the disabled element and don't want to restyle all controls in respect to `IsEnabled` presentation.
- I have tried `IsTabStop` but then I need to wrap my panel/container into a `usercontrol/contentcontrol` and `IsTabStop` is not inherited to children. I don't want to set `IsTabStop` on all controls behind the loading overlay.

I have searched for info on some of the focus related properties but didn't find anything I could use.

Hope someone has a clever solution to my problem

Comment: In WPF, there's `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"` which you could set on the Loading control, does that help you in UWP? It basically prevents the keyboard focus to move outside the given container / control.

Comment: Does the answer work ?

Comment: Yes, ```KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"``` was exactly the magic I was looking for. I have the same thing available in UWP.

Comment: Could you share more detail about `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"`, I have tried, but I could not get it work.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you could handle [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.previewkeydown) of current content then determine <kbd>Tab</kbd> key pressed set `e.Handled = true`.

```
Window.Current.Content.PreviewKeyDown += Content_PreviewKeyDown;

private void Content_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    e.Handled = e.Key == VirtualKey.Tab ? true : false;
}
```

The above code will ignore <kbd>Tab</kbd> pressed in current content.